# The maximum buffer size that we can pass using netlink and PAGE_SIZE influence on it

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel, netlink

I am working on an application (ARM platform) that uses netlink messages to pass a buffer of size 8k to kernel space driver to fetch some data from the driver.  I have allocated the required memory for the nl message using function `nlmsg_alloc_size()`, but when the buffer size **exceeds size of 4k**, we are not getting data from driver, even though the driver is able to receive the netlink command with buffer.

So we checked the kernel source and found that the buffer size is limited to **4096** for **ARM** in kernel.

So is it possible to send netlink message with more than 4k buffer? If so, please suggest a solution.

Comment: I do believe that's the maximum. If you want to send more data, you can always fragment it.

Comment: Hi Yd Ahhrk,
Thanks for the response. I have gone through some links but didn't find any relevant link that describes how we can fragment the big buffer into small ones. So can u please guide me through the relevant link? Or if u don't mind can u please explain.
Thanks in advance